# ionic routing not working like what I expected

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

The structure of my app:

[image]

The main app.js at root:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic',
    'app.intro',
    'app.main',
    'app.services'
])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       ......
    });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
});
```

**app/intro/intro.js:**

```
angular.module('app.intro',['app.intro.controller'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    alert('app.intro');
    $stateProvider
    .state('intro', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/intro/index.html',
        controller: 'IntroCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

**app/intro/controller.js**

```
angular.module('app.intro.controller',[])
    .controller('IntroCtrl',function($scope,$state,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

        $scope.startMain = function() {
            $state.go('main');
        };
    });
```

It works fine. The intro page being shown correctly until I add the **main** module which is a sidemenu.

**app/main/main.js:**

```
angular.module('app.main',['app.main.controller'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/menu.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
.state('main.news', {
    url: '/news',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/news.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('main.share', {
    url: '/share',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'app/main/share.html'
        }
    }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/news');
```

});

The intro page will not be shown anymore. Instead the news page will always be shown when app starts. I'm very new to ionic so that I'm not very familiar with the url routing. Can anybody tell what I did wrong? Thanks.

**Edit:**

**menu.html:**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/main/news">News</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close ng-click="logout()">Logout</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: did you tried to remove alert which you had put in app.intro ? because its seems its blocking the code flow. also what is the purpose behind different .config() and $stateProviders across your modules ? doesn't it complicate the things ?

Comment: Please share your  `menu.html` in question.

Comment: The menu.html added.

Comment: Yes. The alert was removed. It doesn't affect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the "." in your route names, this bit me too but i believe this refers to a substate and wont do a full route transition. If you remove the dots it should work properly.

Also, $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/news'); will default pages to news

Comment: Even the news view showing blank when I replace the **main.news** to **news**.